# function not returning array php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

We have wrote this function to return specific array

```
public function searchArrayMultidimensional($array,$key){
    foreach($array as $k=>$row){
        if($k==$key){
            if(is_array($row)){
                return $row;
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }else{
            $this->searchArrayMultidimensional($row,$key);
        }
    }
}
```

Not issue is while we print inside `foreach` on this line `return $row;` it returns perfect result,

while we call this function or print_r this function using

```
print_r($this->searchArrayMultidimensional($giftProducts,'sku'));
```

its not resulting an array

Actual result : (blank)

Expected result :

```
Array
(
    [0] => HHM1601
    [1] => HHM1602
    [2] => HHM1603
    [3] => HHM1604
    [4] => HHM1605
    [5] => HHM1606
    [6] => HHM1607
)
```

**EDITED **

This is the actual array :

[original array link](https://codeshare.io/tmp)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [196] => Array
                (
                    [sku] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => HHM1601
                            [1] => HHM1602
                            [2] => HHM1603
                            [3] => HHM1604
                            [4] => HHM1605
                            [5] => HHM1606
                            [6] => HHM1607
                        )

                    [qty] => 3.0000
                    [rule_id] => 196
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => IS1617
            [qty] => 1
            [auto_add] => 1
            [rule_id] => 263
            [qtyIncreased] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: share your input also ?

Comment: It would be nice if you provide php array instead output.

Comment: Because of your ambiguous question previously, people got downvotes on their answers. So, please be specific next time.

Comment: @user2486 added link as well

Comment: @SagarPPanchal Created sample demo with your function, working as expected : [check here](https://eval.in/951410)

Comment: @JigarShah : https://eval.in/951411
updated

Comment: is this okay or you want other o/p?

Comment: @JigarShah thanx for contribution but that was not as expected but solved now using below answer

Comment: welcome buddy, I have checked that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change two things in your code: 
write `$k===$key` instead of `$k==$key` and in *else statement* write `return $this->searchArrayMultidimensional($row,$key);`

finally your code should look like:

```
public function searchArrayMultidimensional($array,$key){
    foreach($array as $k=>$row){
        if($k===$key){
            if(is_array($row)){
                return $row;
            }else{
                continue;
            }
        }else{
            return $this->searchArrayMultidimensional($row,$key);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:**

your should write `===` comparison operator because your first key is `0` and when you compare `0` to string with `==` operator it return `true` and your response would be:

```
Array ( [196] => Array ( [sku] => Array ( [0] => HHM1601 [1] => HHM1602 [2] => HHM1603 [3] => HHM1604 [4] => HHM1605 [5] => HHM1606 [6] => HHM1607 ) [qty] => 3 [rule_id] => 196 ) )
```

not

```
Array ( [0] => HHM1601 [1] => HHM1602 [2] => HHM1603 [3] => HHM1604 [4] => HHM1605 [5] => HHM1606 [6] => HHM1607 )
```